# UK visa for husband

Tags: visas, applications, south-africa, passport-renewals

I hold a German passport that has expired, I have applied for a new one but it hasn't arrived yet. My husband has to apply for a UK visa in the mean time. On the application form they ask for his spouse's passport number. Should I put my expired German passport number in or my valid south African passport number (even if I don't intend on traveling with my South African passport)

Comment: The SA passport would be pointless since it doesn't show that your husband is an EU/EEA family member. Do you have an unexpired Personalausweis? Have you considered getting a new German passport first? (And, by the way, have you considered what Brexit might do to the rules?)

Comment: I have applied for a new German passport, but as mentioned above it won't be here in time for my husband to apply for an EEA visa. He needs to travel on his south African passport and I'll travel on my German (which is set to arrive the week before we leave) this is why he is applying for the UK visa in the first place.